# Push value to array after every value not for last

Tags: javascript

// Groups divide with Empty column so insert 0 after every group

const groups=[29,30,31]
I need to insert 0

required output array is:
const groups = [29,0,30,0, 31]

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: this looks like a ' school ' assignment. IF you don't know how to do this. The teacher is doing it wrong

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I asked about my required logic..

Comment: It is expected that you show your attempts to solve your own issue and others help you debug it when it doesn't produce desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const groups = [29,30,31]
for(let i = groups.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
   groups.splice(i, 0, 0)
}
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could use a `forEach` function and insert 0 value before and after elements that have an odd index (except for the last one) like this:

```js
let input = [29,30,31];
let staticVal = 0;

let result = [];
input.forEach((el, i) => {
   if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      result.push(staticVal);
      result.push(el);
      if (i !== input.length - 1) result.push(staticVal);
   }
   else result.push(el);
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `split` to add `0` in between, but it will make all integer to string so a loop to change in integer

```js
const groups=[29,30,31];
var zeroInserted = groups.join(',').replace(/,/g, ',0,').split(',');
zeroInsertedAsInt = zeroInserted.map(e=>parseInt(e));
console.log(zeroInsertedAsInt);
```